# Поиск и замена в реестре

Tags: windows, реестр, powershell

Доброго дня.

**По пути** [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AcroExch.Document.11\shell\Print\command]
**есть ключ** (по умолчанию),
**имеющий значение** *"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /p /h "%1"* или *"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /p /h "%1"*

Если ключ *(по умолчанию)* имеет значение *"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 10.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe" /p /h "%1"* , 
то значение этого ключа необходимо заменить на *"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /p /h "%1"*

Если ключ *(по умолчанию)* имеет значение *"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /p /h "%1"* , 
то скрипт, ничего не изменяя, должен завершиться.

**Обновление**

Для вывода ключа (по умолчанию) из локального реестра я использую скрипт:

```
$k = Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\SessionData\1\'
echo $k.'(default)'
```

Для вывода ключа (по умолчанию) из удалённого реестра я использую скрипт:

```
$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine,'tfarm07')
$key = $reg.OpenSubkey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\SessionData\")
$key.GetSubKeyNames() | ForEach-Object {
        $subkey = $key.OpenSubKey($_)
        $i = @{}
        $i.default = $subkey.GetValue(‘(default)’)
        $i.LoggedOnUsername = $subkey.GetValue(‘LoggedOnUsername’)
        New-Object PSObject -Property $i
        $subkey.Close()
    }
```

Comment: Правильно искать ключ в HKLM:\Software\Classes, а не в HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.

Answer (score 1):

```
$k=Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\\Software\Classes\AcroExch.Document.11\shell\Print\command"
$k."(default)='"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /p /h "%1"'
Set-ItemProperty -InputObject $k # сама подхватит, куда писать
```

Должно работать. В любом случае, замена значения в реестре на то же самое значение не должно создать проблем.